# Удаление и добавление элементов в листе при прохождение через элементы листа

Tags: java

у меня есть List заполненный 14 элементами. Вопрос возможно ли при Stream или другом способе чтения элементов, удалить элементы по меру их чтения и добавлять в конец этого же листа?

```
public List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<>();//1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
//после Stream List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<>(); 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1
    public void addVideo(Video video) {
        videos.add(video);
    }

    public Stream<Video> videos() {
        return videos.stream();
    }
```

Comment: возможно *(нужно ещё 2 символа...)*

Comment: что имеете в виду?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119039/how-do-you-build-an-infinite-repeating-stream-from-a-finite-stream-in-java-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно сдвинуть несколько элементов в списке по кругу *один раз*, проще всего воспользоваться методом [`Collections::rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-):

```java
List<Integer> videos = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14);
Collections.rotate(videos, -1);
// -> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1]
```

---

Если же нужно получить бесконечную последовательность на базе заданного списка с первоначальным сдвигом: `[a, b, c, d] -> c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b...`, следует воспользоваться методом [`IntStream::iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) из Stream API:

```java
private static <T> Stream<T> shifted(List<T> list, int start) {
    final int n = list.size();
    return IntStream.iterate(start - 1, i -> (i + 1) % n).mapToObj(list::get);
}

System.out.println(
    shifted(Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 2)
        .limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList())
);

// -> [b, c, d, a, b, c, d, a, b, c]
```

Comment: rotate() метод очень помог, спасибо